# timezone javascript in my timer

Tags: javascript, php, timer, timezone

I have found a code but i dont know to add timezone . i want to detect the timer from the timezone of the other country like denmark/copenhagen. thank you. this is my code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
ElapsedTimeLogger = function(dateElementId, elapsedElementId, hiden, interval) {
    var container = $(elapsedElementId);
    var time = parseDate($(dateElementId).val());
    var interval = interval;
    var timer;

    function parseDate(dateString) {
        var date = new Date(dateString);
        return date.getTime();
    }

    function update() {
    var systemTime = new Date().getTime();
    elapsedTime = systemTime - time;
    container.html(prettyPrintTime(Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000)));
$(hiden).val(prettyPrintTime(Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000)));
}

    function prettyPrintTime(numSeconds) {
        var hours = Math.floor(numSeconds / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((numSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = numSeconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
        var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        return time;
    }

    this.start = function() {

        timer = setInterval(function() {update()}, interval * 1000);
    }

    this.stop = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeLogger = new ElapsedTimeLogger("#date", "#elapsed","#stoppedid", 1);
    timeLogger.start();

   $("#confirm").click(function() { //Stop timer upon clicking the Confirm Button 
        timeLogger.stop();

    });

});

    </script>
```

thank you. i dont know javascript. i know php only. i tried to put

before the code is running. i already save a time from europe/copenhagen. but when the timer is running. it says 6:00:01 abd counting.. but i want to run like this 0:00:01 and counting. and my idea the time from europe and time in my country is 6 hours.  i want to run the time from europe not my country. because i save the time from europe using php. see bellow the code for save the time.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Copenhagen");
```

but wont work. i didnt found the solution

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking.  What do you mean by "to add timezone" and "detect the timer from the timezone"?  Please be specific.

Comment: sorry for that.. what i mean is. i save a time using time from denmark. when i query the time and start for running the time. it say 6:00:00 i a hoping the out put will be 0:00:01 . in my thoughts time from denmark and time from my country is between 6hours. thats why i want to run my timer from the denmark time. where i save the time. hope you understand. sorry for my english

Comment: To be clear, are you asking for a countdown timer that is based on an input date and time in a specific time zone?  Have you considered that the easier approach would be to convert the input to UTC on the server and then countdown to the UTC time instead?

Comment: I dont know what is the term for that sir. but exactly you get my point. can you help me for that sir?

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing this code, I rewrote the needed HTML to see what the code do. It's simply creates a counter in format hh:mm:ss and shows on screen, this counter show the time passed since the date informed.

to add the user timezone to reflect in your timer, you just need to recalculate the seconds inside the `prettyPrintTime(numSeconds)` function before use it to get hours, minutes and seconds.

```
function prettyPrintTime(numSeconds) {
            var tzOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();  // get the timezone in minutes
            tzOffset = tzOffset * 60;   // convert minutes to seconds
            numSeconds -= tzOffset;     // recalculate the time using timezone

            var hours = Math.floor(numSeconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((numSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
            var seconds = numSeconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

            if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
            if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
            if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
            var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

            return time;
        }
```

Take a look at the working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/4c6xdcpr/

Answer (score -1):

```
function getClientTimeZone() {
  var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
    o = Math.abs(offset);
  return (offset < 0 ? "+" : "-") + ("00" + Math.floor(o / 60)).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + (o % 60)).slice(-2);
}

// Display Output
alert(getClientTimeZone());
```

Comment: how to add that one to my code? i dont kinow. because i dont know javascript.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].